# How to communicate with LibGDX HTML5 app?

Tags: javascript, java, html, libgdx

I'm pretty comfortable with [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) aimed at a desktop deployment and I'm trying to extend into the HTML5 cross-compilation deployments that it makes possible.

Is there any way I can pass data from a HTML form or Javascript running on the same page into the LibGDX app when deployed to HTML5? I want to have a form sat next to the canvas, which on submission passes data into the app. Or any other method of using the HTML page as a UI to pass data in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't know much about the topic myself but the question is quite interesting and I think I managed to get somewhere with some digging around. What I'm suggesting might not be the best way to do it so take it with a pinch of salt.

From what I've read, I think the best way forward is to use the GWT JNSI to put native javascript within your `HtmlLauncher.java` file which should be found somewhere in your `html/src` sub-directory.

Examples of how to structure the native functions include the `libGDX` backends themselves and another link I found online:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/

https://github.com/piotr-j/dungen/blob/master/html/src/io/piotrjastrzebski/dungen/client/HtmlLauncher.java#L59

The second example is an actual game which defines javascript to be called on the HTML5 platform when necessary. By following these examples it shouldn't be too hard to make a function like `getData` which queries the DOM for your data and returns it to the game. Hopefully this helps somewhat.

Comment: That's some fantastic digging, thanks! I'll give it a go, hope I can get it working :)